# How to perform operations on matrices of non-matching size

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

```
A = rand(4,2);
B = rand(4,3)
```

Now after performing some operations on `B` (roots, derivative etc) we get a new matrix `B1`, whose dimensions are `size(B1)` = `size(B)`,

The operation I want to perform

```
B.' * ( A - B1.')
```

Like when each element of `B.'` multiplies with `A`, at that same time, The corresponding element from element `B1` gets subtracted from `A` before multiplication.

The final dimensions need to be of What we would usually get from multiplication of `B.' * A`

Note - dimensions of intialized matrices change at each runtime so no manual operations

**EXAMPLE**

Lets say we have

```
A = 2x2 
     [ x1, x2 ]
     [ y1, y2 ]
```

and

```
B = 2X1
     [a1]
     [b1]
```

and

```
B1 = 2x1
     [a11]
     [b11]
```

So during a simple multiplication of `B.' * A`

```
 [(a1 * x1 + b1 * y1), (a1 * x2 + b1 * y2)]
```

I want to subtract `B1` such that

```
 [ (a1 * (x1-a11) + b1 * (y1-b11)),  (a1 * (x2-a11) + b1 * (y2-b11))]
```

Example inputs of different size:

INPUTS

```
   B = 
    [ a1 b1; 

      a2 b2;  

      a3 b3;

      a4 b4]

  A = 

  [ x11 x12 x13; 

    x21 x22 x23;

    x31 x32 x33; 

    x41 x42 x43]

  B1 =

  [a10 b10;

   a20 b20;

   a30 b30;

   a40 b40]


Result =

 [b1(x11-b10)+b2(x21-b20)+b3(x31-b30)+b4(x41-b40) b1(x12-b10)+b2(x22-b20)+b3(x32-b30)+b4(x42-b40) b1(x13-b10)+b2(x23-b20)+b3(x33-b30)+b4(x43-b40);


 a1(x11-a10)+a2(x21-a20)+a3(x31-b30)+a4(x41-a40) a1(x12-a10)+a2(x22-a20)+a3(x32-a30)+a4(x42-a40) a1(x13-a10)+a2(x23-a20)+a3(x33-a30)+a4(x43-a40)]
```

Comment: How do you plan on subtracting a 4 x 3 from a 4 x 2 matrix?

Comment: Please provide a numeric example of inputs and outputs.

Comment: @Suever Check the updated description!

Comment: @Dev-iL Example Added!

Comment: Please learn to [format your question](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) bold formatting is rarely necessary and makes a post hard to read. Additionally there's a thing called "code formatting" please actually use it for code, don't make everything bold or quote-yellow or any other type of painful-eyes-formatting-disco.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear until example input and desired output using the actual matrix dimensions are provided.

Comment: @beaker Added inputs and desired outputs in required format

Comment: @Adriaan I know, I didn't use it intentionally but the website was detecting it as code and wasn't letting me post until I code quoted it

Comment: You never use the last rows of `A` and `B1`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @beaker Guys, please reopen the post, for now it's  clear. It's not just some curiosity, I really need this thing to be implemented in my code!

Comment: @beaker last rows? for a square matrix? Only one dimension matches between A and B1, B1's dimension is always = B's dimension, It's like Matrix Multiplication between B' and A only that elements of B1 are subtracted from A before getting multipied with elements of B'

Comment: I'm talking about your latest update under `INPUTS`. There's not a single square matrix in there. Your matrix multiplication doesn't make any sense. The dimensions of `B` do not match the dimensions of `B1`. `x14 x42 x43` and `a40 b40` are never used.

Comment: @beaker corrected!

Comment: Okay, so we're back to my previous (deleted) comment: Let `B1 = [B1 B1(:,2)]` and use Suever's solution. Incidentally, I think you still have the rows of the result reversed.

Comment: @beaker error: bsxfun: nonconformant dimensions: 2x4 and 4x4

Comment: Actually, you don't need the `bsxfun` at all. Once you have the matrices in the proper dimensions you can just multiply them normally.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that `size(B,2) >= size(A,2)`:

```
A = rand(4,2);
B = rand(4,3);
B1 = rand(size(B)).*B;
res = B' * ( A - B1(:,1:size(A,2)))
```

Comment: Please check the example in the description, I want to subtract each element of B1 from each element of A